# Can you switch or view a friends role in Disney's Dreamlight Valley?

Tags: disney-dreamlight-valley

In the game, Disney's Dreamlight Valley, for the Nintendo Switch, you can assign a role to your friends in the valley. Roles such as, Mining, Fishing, Etc. These roles give you a bonus when they follow you and you perform those roles.

Is there a way to view existing roles, and can you switch them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can view their role but you cannot change it.

To view the role, go to Collection, Characters, and select the character and it will be at the bottom:

[image]